# DIV display: table-cell and text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablecell

I have the following css attributes:

```
.sigSign { 
  display:table; 
  position:absolute; 
  border:1px solid #2ECC71; 
  outline:0; 
  text-align:center; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
.sigSign div {  
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align:center; 
}
```

And I have the following:

```
<div class="sigSign" style="width: 50px;height: 32px;">something really long in here</div>
<div class="sigSign" style="width: 50px;height: 32px;">short text</div>
```

With both the elements being 50px in width, one is quite larger then the other because of the text inside. The reason why I did `display:table-cell` is so that I can do a vertical align because the height of the element is always changing.

Is there a way to make the elements the same width, and just have the ellipsis if the text goes beyond the width and still use the table attributes?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3q0o7fx/) so that you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: `.sigSign div { display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center;}` isn't being applied; your `sigSign` elements don't contain any divs. They are currently using `display:table` instead, since that is what you set for your `.sigSign` class. You need a container element with `display:table` and your inner elements (sigSign) would then have `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 1):

child `div` missing in your fiddle

### html

```
<div class="sigSign" style="width: 50px;height: 32px;">
    <div>something really long in here</div>
</div>
```

add `table-layout: fixed;` on "table" `div`

### css

```
.sigSign {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #2ECC71;
    outline: 0;
    text-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.sigSign div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3q0o7fx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said, there's no anonymous divs for the second rule set to hook into, so I combined the 2 rulesets. Now both divs are 50px wide regardless of content and the ellipses are functioning as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/xhs0y3n7/

```
.sigSign {
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #2ECC71;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Your CSS is similar to David Walsh's snippet published in this [article](https://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis).

```
  .dataTable td {
    /* essential */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* for good looks */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Notice he uses a real `td` so your'e thinking along the same lines as he is.